# Getting a inner value from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I wrote a unit test trying to pull out a title node from a response from a YouTube request. The xml comes back fine. But I cannot seem to pull out the title, trying multiple different paths. Thanks for any help.

Unit Test

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo");
string urlContents = await getStringTask;
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(urlContents);
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/entry/title");
```

Results from Request

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo</id>
    <published>2010-07-08T03:08:21.000Z</published>
    <updated>2013-05-11T12:01:32.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Entertainment' label='Entertainment'/>
    <title type='text'>Chelsea Lately: Pharrell</title>
    <content type='text'>Pharrell chats about his latest animated film "Despicable Me." Plus, the hip-hop artist discusses his presidential friendships. Watch it!</content>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5QAfTGVxuo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo/responses'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo/related'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=t5QAfTGVxuo'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo'/>
    <author>
        <name>ChelseaLately</name>
        <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ChelseaLately</uri>
    </author>
    <gd:comments>
        <gd:feedLink rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo/comments' countHint='1935'/>
    </gd:comments>
    <media:group>
        <media:category label='Entertainment' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Entertainment</media:category>
        <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/t5QAfTGVxuo?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='5'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v8.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnqxpUxfQCUtxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='1'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v8.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnqxpUxfQCUtxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='6'/>
        <media:description type='plain'>Pharrell chats about his latest animated film "Despicable Me." Plus, the hip-hop artist discusses his presidential friendships. Watch it!</media:description>
        <media:keywords/>
        <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5QAfTGVxuo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:03:07.500'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:33.750'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:03:07.500'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:04:41.250'/>
        <media:title type='plain'>Chelsea Lately: Pharrell</media:title>
        <yt:duration seconds='375'/>
    </media:group>
    <gd:rating average='4.8778543' max='5' min='1' numRaters='3766' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
    <yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='1571771'/>
</entry>
```

Comment: Always enjoy a looong line of xml... :p

Comment: Only thing I am trying to get out of there is the Title. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I think if you took some time splitting up and formatting the xml, you will either find the answer yourself, or someone might actually want to answer this question. (friendly tip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your XPath query is failing is because the XML contains a namespace. You need to use a `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo");
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("t", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var title = doc.SelectSingleNode("/t:entry/t:title", nsm);
Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
```

or if you prefer using the new XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo");
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsm.AddNamespace("t", doc.Root.Name.NamespaceName);
var title = doc.XPathSelectElement("/t:entry/t:title", nsm);
Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
```